# Dante Socks Multiple instances

Tags: linux, bash, proxy, socks, dante

I have correctly installed Dante on Ubuntu server as a proxy, and it works, but I must have e multiple instances of it (each of them has to works in different port).

I have tried it in this way:

```
tomas@server: $ sudo cp /etc/sockd.conf /etc/sockd222.conf
tomas@server: $ sudo nano /etc/sockd222.conf

logoutput: /var/log/socks222.log
internal: enp0s3 port = 1081
external: enp0s3
[...]

tomas@server: $ sudo cp /etc/init.d/sockd /etc/init.d/sockd222
tomas@server: $ sudo nano /etc/init.d/sockd222
NAME=sockd222
[...]

tomas@server: $ sudo /etc/init.d/sockd222 start
```

But this doesn't work because the file [/etc/init.d/sockd](https://github.com/weheartwebsites/SOCKS5/wiki/Install-a-SOCKS5-server-(Dante)-on-Debian-Wheezy#install) Isn't programmed for multiple instances. How do I need to edit that file to allow it?

Thank you

Comment: You probably need to modify the sockd222 init script to load your  /etc/sockd222.conf configuration file. How? That depends on the current init script, but `sockd` supports a `-f /path/to/file` option to specify a configuration file on a non-standard location...

Comment: Yes Sir,
I avoided to insert all code, but the variable NAME=sockd222 is used for: CONFFILE=/etc/$NAME.conf

And the multiple instances must be at the same time.